# Skip .spec files only for SonarTS and not TSLint

Tags: angular, tslint, sonarlint

I want to set up SonarTS inside of my Angular 6 project, but when running my `lint` npm script I get code analysis of my .spec files too. Sometimes duplication in my .spec files is desirable, so how can I deactivate this, without skipping linting for my .spec files?

npm script in **package.json**

```
"lint": "tslint -p src/tsconfig.tslint.json -t stylish -c tslint.json",
```

devDependency in **package.json**

```
"tslint-sonarts": "^1.7.0",
```

**tslint.json**

```
"extends": [
    "@ns/tslint-presets/tslint.recommended.angular.json",
    "tslint-config-prettier",
    "tslint-sonarts"
],
```

**tsconfig.json** (this also skips linting, not desired!)

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
],
```

Comment: Did you figure this one? I am in a similar situation, where I get 'no-identical-function' in spec files. I want to omit this rule only for spec files.